# Div positioning problem related to Relative and Absolute positioning

Tags: css, html

The problem I am running into is related to a footer I have absolutely positioned at the bottom of the page.  Everything is fine until the copy on the page begins to extend further down the page which then causes my content wells to extend down, behind, the footer. Is there anyway I can force my content wells to 'push' the footer down the page?

Here is the relevant html:

```
   <div id="page">
      <div id="page_container">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="nav"></div>
        <div id="main_content">
              <div id="left_column"></div>
              <div id="right_column"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
     <div id="footer_container">
     </div>
   </div>
```

And the relevant CSS

```
 #page            {width:100%;margin:0 0 10px 0; text-align:center;}
 #page_container  {width:743px;height:auto !important;height:100%;margin:0 auto;min-height:100%;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;border:2px solid #000;}
 #header          {width:100%;background:url('../images/header.jpg');height:87px;clear:both; margin-top: -2px;}
 #nav             {width:100%;height:29px;float:left; text-align:left; border-bottom: solid 2px #000; border-top: solid 2px #000;}
 #main_content    {width:100%;float:left; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; border-bottom: solid 2px #000; border-left: solid 2px #000; border-right: solid 2px #000;}
 #footer          {width:100%; position:absolute;margin-top:10px; bottom: 0; background:url('../images/footer_bg.jpg');height:133px;text-align:center;}
 #footer_container{width:746px;height:133px; text-align:left; display:inline-block;}
 #left_column     {width:230px; float:left; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; margin-top:5px;}
 #right_column    {width:490px; float:right; text-align:left; background-color:#fff;margin-top:5px; padding:10px;}
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to give!

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed;` for the footer, you also might want to have some `padding-bottom` for your `body` so that the content won't go under it.

Comment: Thanks reko but that didn't change the footer behavior.  My main content well is still falling  behind the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the *height: 100%* on pageContainer - that fixes the div to the window height and not the content height.

Comment: Hey Steve. Thanks for your response but that seemed to have no effect.  When I shrink the browser window so that the text will expand down the page the content well is still going behind the footer.

Comment: Did you do anything with the height: auto portion?  I don't think that will do great things either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
 html, body { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }       
 #page_container { width:743px; margin:0 auto; }
 #header { height:87px; border:1px solid #000; }
 #footer { height:133px; position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; border:1px solid #000;}
 #nav { height:29px; border:1px solid #000;}
 #left_column { width:230px; float:left; border:1px solid #000;}
 #right_column { width:490px; float:left; border:1px solid #000;}

 #page { min-height:100%; position:relative; }
 #main_content { padding-bottom:133px; }
 .clear { clear:both; }
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
#container {
    height:100%;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

HTML (note - you must put #footer inside #page for this method to work):

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="page_container">
        <div id="header">hhhh</div>
        <div id="nav">nav</div>
        <div id="main_content">
            <div id="left_column">lll</div>
            <div id="right_column">rrr</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer_container">fffff</div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

You can preview working example here: http://www.front-end-developer.net/examples/bottomfooter/footer.htm

Tested on Chrome, Firefox, IE6, IE7, IE8 and Opera.

Comment: Fantastic!  One question though: how do I add a top margin so that the page does not rest up against the top of the browser window without causing a scroll bar to appear? Adding a margin to any of the containers (Page, page_container, header) causes a scroll bar to appear.  Thanks!